# Erro ao criar novo usuario no Moodle via webservice

Tags: php, moodle, web-service

Tenho tentado adicionar um novo usuário ao Moodle utilizando sua api webservice

Já modifiquei inúmeras vezes os parâmetros passados via post, testei usar um array ao invés de um objeto, testei algumas mudanças na estrutura do array que é passado, mas sempre obtenho a mesma resposta do moodle:

**"Missing required key in single structure: users"**

A resposta:

```php
{
    "exception":"invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode":"invalidparameter",
    "message":"Valor inv\u00e1lido de par\u00e2metro detectado",
    "debuginfo":"Missing required key in single structure: users"
}
```

Meu código:

```php
$functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
$user1 = new stdClass();
$user1->id = 1;  //
$user1->username = 'testusername1';
$user1->password = 'testpassword1';
$user1->firstname = 'testfirstname1';
$user1->lastname = 'testlastname1';
$user1->email = 'testemail1@moodle.com';
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$user1->idnumber = 'testidnumber1';
$user1->description = 'Hello World!';
$user1->city = 'testcity1';
$user1->country = 'BR';

$token = 'mytoken';
$domainname = 'localhost/moodle';
$functionname = 'core_user_create_users';
$restformat = 'json';
$serverurl = $domainname . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . $token . '&wsfunction='.$functionname.'&moodlewsrestformat=' . $restformat;

$users = array($user1);
$params = array('users' => $users); 

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',                    
        'header' => 'Content-Type: text/plain',
        'content' => $params                             
    )
));

$contents = file_get_contents($serverurl, null, $context);            

//print_r($contents);

$resposta = json_decode($contents);
```

Pelo que chequei, todas os campos obrigatórios estão preenchidos.

Estou utilizando um token valido, e o usuário possui a permissão necessária para utilizar a função  `core_user_create_users`.

Usei o seguinte código como [base](https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients/blob/master/PHP-REST/client.php)

**UPDATE**

Entre os **erros comuns** ao tentar criar um usuário via webservice estão

- Tentar cadastrar campo obrigatório com valor vazio
- Tentar cadastrar senha que não atenda a politica de senhas definida na  configuração do moodle
- Esquecer de encapsular o(s) objeto(s) com as informações do(s) usuário(s) em um array e chavear como 'users'

  ```
  $users = array($user1, $user2);
  $params = array('users' => $users);
  ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse erro poderá estar relacionado com política de senhas do Moodle que por defeito obriga a que a senha contenha:

> Mínimo de caracteres: 8
>   Mínimo de números: 1
>   Mínimo de letras maiúsculas: 1
>   Mínimo de letras minúsculas: 1
>   Mínimo de caracteres não alfanuméricos: 1

<sup>Informação pode ser lida [aqui](http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Site_policies#Password_policy).</sup>

Verifica se estás realmente a respeitar estes requisitos.

---

**Notas:**
Estas definições pode ser alteradas nas políticas do site em:

> Settings → Site administration → Security → Site policies.

Comment: Eu havia realizado testes com outras senhas, `$user1->password =  'Password123!';` Mas vou verificar as definições de segurança apesar disso.

Comment: Apenas para enriquecimento: Eu encontrei [**este tópico**](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=173181) em que o problema era muito parecido. A solução acertiva foi a mesma que a sugerida pelo amigo.

Comment: Cheguei a desativar a politica de senhas. Mas não mudou nada.

Comment: @EdgarMunizBerlinck eu já havia esbarrado nesse tópico anteriormente  também...

Comment: Não consegui recordar exatamente como resolvi a situação, então atualizei a pergunta mencionando os erros mais comuns que encontrei nos testes que fiz com o webservice do Moodle

Answer (score 2):

**Solucionado com Moodle 3.6.2+ (Build: 20190222)**

**invalidparameter**

Eu passei por um problema parecido e vou relatar aqui. Espero que seja util para alguem algum dia, pois foi dificil achar quando precisei.

Eu usei como ponto de partida esse codigo aqui:
https://github.com/moodlehq/sample-ws-clients/blob/master/PHP-REST/client.php

O que gerou erro "invalidparameter" foi, basicamente, essa linha:

```
$user1->theme = 'standard';
```

Foi só comentar a linha do tema que o Moodle quase aceitou. Digo quase porque, quando me livrei do erro de "invalidparameter", o Moodle lançou o erro "forcepasswordchangenotice"

**forcepasswordchangenotice**

Esse erro foi lançado porque não havia logado nenhuma vez com o usuário que criei para usar o webservice. Quando loguei com ele, o Moodle pediu para que eu mudasse a senha. Assim que mudei a senha ele desbloqueou o usuario para usar o webservice, e agora esta tudo OK.

Finalmente, consegui criar um usuario passando esses valores aqui:

```
$rand = rand(1,1000000);
$user1->username = "testusername$rand";
$user1->password = 'Testp@123';
$user1->firstname = "testfirstname";
$user1->lastname = 'testlastname1';
$user1->email = "$rand@moodle.com";
$user1->auth = 'manual';
$user1->idnumber = "testidnumber$rand";
$user1->lang = 'pt_br';
$user1->mailformat = 0;
$user1->description = 'Hello World!';
$user1->city = 'testcity1';
$user1->country = 'br';
```